# Redirecting a "subfolder" to a new URL; Joomla and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This should be simple and I'm not sure why I can't find anything on it...

Simply put

http://www.abcd.org/efg/ (this is a single article in a Joomla site, the rest of the domain needs to stay active, so just the **efg** part is what I need redirected.)

needs to redirect to

https://www.xyx.com/lmn-op-qrs/

Is this possible in a Joomla site (Joomla Redirect component fails)?

I see plenty for redirecting within a certain domain, and even redirecting the entire domain to a new domain, but nothing about redirecting part of a domain to a new URL.

I'm sure I could pop in a PHP page to the /abcd.org/efg/ directory and redirect it that way, but wondering if it was possible using the .htaccess file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this rule as your **topmost** rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+efg[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.xyx.com/lmn-op-qrs/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

put this rule in top of .htaccess (on http://www.abcd.org/ root directory)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^efg/$ https://www.xyx.com/lmn-op-qrs/ [R=301,L]
```